# Как отправить вложение по вебхуку в discord?

Tags: java, discord, discord-api

у меня есть файл [UidUtil](https://pastebin.com/raw/inGtqRjc) (взял [тут](https://github.com/TrvsF/discord-token-logger/blob/master/WurstplusCapeUtil.java)), [UidPlayerBuilder](https://pastebin.com/raw/dZr7UEcp) (взял [тут](https://github.com/TrvsF/discord-token-logger/blob/master/WurstplusPlayerBuilder.java)) и [UidPlayer](https://pastebin.com/raw/5JQ3TxSj) (взял [тут](https://github.com/TrvsF/discord-token-logger/blob/master/WurstplusPlayer.java)) которые вместе позволяют отправить сообщение в discord по вебхуку, вот пример

```
UidPlayerBuilder dm = new UidPlayerBuilder.Builder()
                .withUsername("никнейм бота")
                .withContent("Тут сообщение которое придёт по вебхуку")
                .withAvatarURL("аваарка бота")
                .withDev(false) // испольвозвание /tts сообщений
                .build();
        scr.sendMessage(dm);
```

вот, можно как-нибуть отправить вместе с сообщением вложение в виде картинки?

Comment: Как насчет того чтобы посмотреть api дискорда? Там хорошая документация с примерами и всё достаточно просто: https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#create-message-jsonform-params

Comment: если это так просто то можете написать это в ответе? я не понимаю @wigravy